# How to transliterate 中文 in Mandarin pronunciation to Italian?

Tags: pronunciation

I am working on an art project where I would like to collect hundreds of different transliterations of 「中文」 zhōng wén in Mandarin Chinese. (Pronunciation available here: [https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/de/中文](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/de/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87))

How can I transliterate zhōng wén in Italian? (For example, "zhong wen" would be the closest pronunciation in English.)

Comment: If you want a phonetic description I'd say *gion uen* or *scion uen* but usually when we want to write Chinese words in Italian we use either Pinyin or Wade-Giles.

Comment: Semi-serious comment: probably the closest approximation that you can convey to the average Italian is "it's pronounced like [John Wayne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wayne)".

Answer (score 2):

Since you say that you are collecting hundreds of transliterations, I assume that you already considered all the standard romanizations, and are searching for more specific italian transliterations.
From what I could hear, 中 could be gion, cion or scion, while 文 could be uen or uein.

Answer (score 2):

Ciao, per caso ho visto questa domanda. Sono cinese, e mi pare che 
中 si pronuncia come /g(g di gi)-on/ [dʒ-o-ŋ] ("cion or scion" are totally wrong).
---------文 [uen]. Come "ven" di vendere, ma non si usa i denti a sfiorare il labro, quindi "u" è più vicino. Ciao!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend **ciognuen**.

The sounds written in IPA (sans tones) would clarify exactly what is different:

- Standard Mandarin: /ʈ͡ʂʊŋu̯ən/
- Standard Italian: /t͡ʃoɲwen/

The choice of **ci** over **gi** is due to the fact that Italian does not have aspirated plosives, and Mandarin does not have voiced plosives. So in transliterating as close as possible to what is spoken, you also lose the contrast between initials like **b** and **p** as they both reduce to **p**.

The **ng** sound in Mandarin is an allophone in Italian as in the word **banconota**. The sound does not appear alone and cannot be written alone. So, the next closest substitute is the Italian **gn**.

The sound sequences can be found in native Italian words, so it *should* be fairly pronounceable to the Italian speaker:

- **cio**ccolata
- **ognu**no
- eloq**uen**za